# how to add a selected row value from child to parent?

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

[image: page image]

**parent controller**

```
public String name {get; set;}
public String phone {get; set;}
public String email {get; set;}

private List<Contact> contactList;
public void addMore() {

string nameT = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('nameT');
string phoneT = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('phoneT');
string emailT = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('emailT');

system.debug(nameT + '//' + phoneT + '//' + emailT);


Contact att = new Contact();

att.lastname = nameT;
att.phone = phoneT;
att.email = emailT;
// it returns

contactList.add(att);
```

**parent page**

```
<script> 
    function str1(name,phone,email)
    {  
        console.log(name + '//' + phone+ '//' + email);
        valueSet(name, phone, email);
    }
</script>

<input type="hidden" id="cname" value="str1()"/>
<apex:actionFunction action="{!addMore}" name="valueSet" reRender="table_panel">
    <apex:param name="nameT" value=""/>
    <apex:param name="phoneT" value=""/>
    <apex:param name="emailT" value=""/>
</apex:actionFunction>
```

**Child page**

```
<script> 
    function addRow(index)
    {  
        console.log(index);
        var nameVal = document.getElementById('contactName_'+index).value;
        var phoneVal = document.getElementById('contactPhone_'+index).value;
        var emailVal = document.getElementById('contactEmail_'+index).value;
        console.log(nameVal);
        console.log(phoneVal);
        console.log(emailVal);

        window.opener.str1(nameVal,phoneVal,emailVal);
        window.opener.winClose();
    }
</script>
<apex:outputPanel id="pnlSearchResults" style="margin:10px;height:350px;overflow-Y:auto;" layout="block">
    <apex:variable var="index" value="{!0}"/>
    <apex:pageBlock id="searchResults"> 
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!results}" var="a" id="tblResults">

            <apex:column>
                <apex:facet name="header">
                    <apex:outputPanel >Name</apex:outputPanel>
                </apex:facet> 
                <a id="clickFtn" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="addRow('{!index}')">  
                    <input type="hidden" value="{!a.name}" id="contactName_{!index}"/>
                    <input type="hidden" value="{!a.phone}" id="contactPhone_{!index}"/>
                    <input type="hidden" value="{!a.email}" id="contactEmail_{!index}"/>
                    {!a.Name}
                </a>
                <apex:variable var="index" value="{!index+1}"/>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column id="contactPhone">
                <apex:facet name="header">
                    <apex:outputPanel >Phone</apex:outputPanel>
                </apex:facet>
                {!a.Phone}
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column id="contactEmail">
                <apex:facet name="header">
                    <apex:outputPanel >Email</apex:outputPanel>
                </apex:facet>
                {!a.Email}
            </apex:column>

        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

situation is , get selected child parameter value  1. name , 2.phone 3.email  and put them in the selected list on the contact standard page / add on parent under row. but it won't works well..